# How to get video URL using Youtube data API v3.0?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

How can i get video URL using YouTube data API(JAVA)?

Answer (score 0):

You cant! use www.youtube.com/get_video_info API

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I think it does. The user needed to know how can he get the url and the answer is he can't. So I provided him with a different way. If you still not convince then please let me know

Comment: @therealprashant - it would be helpful if you provide more information about this API.  I don't see any details of it listed in the [youtube API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/activities), so some kind of link describing what it does and how to use it would be beneficial.